# Trying to call an instance method outputs AttributeError: object has no attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

i'm trying to run a simple python script, but somehow i got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Script' object has no attribute 'run'
```

My code looks like this:

```
class Script(object):
  def __init__(self, data1, data2, data3):
     self.data1 = data1
     self.data2 = data2
     self.data3 = data3

     def getData1(self):
         return self.data1

     def getData2(self):
         return self.data2

     def getData3(self):
         return self.data3

     def run(self):
         return 'Running successfully'

 script1 = Script('data1', 'data2', 'data3')
 print script1.run()
```

Would be great if someone can help me :)

Comment: Please fix your indentation. It's likely the cause of your problem, but the code in the question just throws an IndentationError.

Comment: It looks like all your methods are defined inside the `__init__` method rather than in the class. De-denting them by 1 level should fix your problem.

Comment: your run() and other methods() are defined under __init__() identation

Comment: thanks its working now :)

Comment: Voted to close on the basis of typographical error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your run() and other methods() are defined under **init**() identation 
Try this:-

```
class Script(object):
    def __init__(self, data1, data2, data3):
        self.data1 = data1
        self.data2 = data2
        self.data3 = data3

    def getData1(self):
        return self.data1

    def getData2(self):
        return self.data2

    def getData3(self):
        return self.data3

    def run(self):
        return 'Running successfully'

script1 = Script('data1', 'data2', 'data3')
print script1.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

From the way the code is formatted in your question, it seems like all functions `getData1`, `getData2`, `getData3` and `run` are closures of the method `__init__`, not methods of the class themselves.
This means that they are not methods of the object instance, and hence not accessible from outside `__init__`.

You can reformat the code to look like this instead

```
class Script(object):
    def __init__(self, data1, data2, data3):
        self.data1 = data1
        self.data2 = data2
        self.data3 = data3

    def getData1(self):
        return self.data1

    def getData2(self):
        return self.data2

    def getData3(self):
        return self.data3

    def run(self):
        return 'Running successfully'

script1 = Script('data1', 'data2', 'data3')
print script1.run()
```

which will make all the functions mentioned above methods of the class.

Answer (score 0):

From the first look, you should fix the indentation on the second line.